# "combining diacritical marks for symbols" combine with what?

Tags: unicode

I am trying to combine a symbol from the font range "combining diacritical marks for symbols" (20D5, Combining Clockwise Arrow Above) with an ordinary letter, and no luck. In fact, I don't seem to be able to combine it with any other character.

Now, I'm attempting this in MS Word 2010, using Arial Unicode MS, but I'm suspecting this is a question about unicode font combining rules, not about Word per se. (And FWIW, I do know the Word procedure to combine a normal diacritical with a normal character).

So the name of the group that 20D5 belongs to says "for symbols". So perhaps there's a rule that says it must combine only with "symbols". So I tried it with Currency Symbols, Letterlike Symbols, Miscellaneous Symbols, and no success.

So what characters are these "combining diacritical marks for symbols" supposed to combine with?

Comment: The combining mark shows *intent*, it is still up to the text rendering engine to make it happen.  U+20D5 seems to be too quirky when I try it in a quicky Winforms app, it doesn't fall back on a font like SegoeUI and with ArialUnicode it refuses to combine.  Their might be a language-specific font where this kind of diacritic is normal, I don't know any language that does.

Comment: I experimented with \p{Symbol} and \p{Letter} characters on my system, I get reasonable results. Try freetype and DejaVu fonts.

Comment: @daxim You're right! In Word 2010, symbol 20D5 from font DejaVu Math TeX Gyre does indeed combine with letters, with the letter font being DejaVu, or some other font.  Thanks!